# How do I open a file for reading in a separate function without getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I open a file in a single function, it opens without error.

```
void fileOpen(char fileName[]){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(file != NULL) {
        printf("Successfully opened.");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Successfully opened.
```

However, when I try to move the process to a separate function, the file opens, but with a segmentation fault.

```
void fileOpen(FILE file, char fileName[]){
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(file != NULL) {
        printf("Successfully opened.");
    }
}

void fileStart(){
    FILE *mainFile;
    char name[] = "file.txt";
    fileOpen(mainFile, name);
}
```

Output:

```
Successfully opened.
segmentation fault (core dumped) ./executable
```

If this is an error with how i'm passing the variables please explain. Pointers are a weak point for me.

Comment: Hint: Why does `void f(int i) {i = 5;} int main() {int x = 2; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` not print 5?

Comment: Sit back and meditate about the meaning of "**local** variable" (in contrast to "**global** variable").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You want your function `void fileOpen` to modify its first parameter, which you want it to be of type FILE*. Hence, the first parameter should be a pointer to such pointer:

```
void fileOpen(FILE** file, char fileName[]){
    *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(*file != NULL) {
        printf("Successfully opened.");
    }
}
```

2) in `fileStart`, call your function correctly by providing it all the parameters it needs, with the correct types:

```
void fileStart(){
    FILE *mainFile;
    fileOpen(&mainFile, "someFileName");
}
```

p.s: you could better let the function `fileOpen` return the pointer instead of modifying a parameter. Actually, the "good" way to do this stuff is:

```
   FILE* fileOpen(char fileName[]){
        FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
        if(file != NULL) {
            printf("Successfully opened.");
        }
        return file;
    }
    void fileStart(){
        FILE* mainFile = fileOpen("someFileName");
        if(mainFile == NULL){
         ... error, do something
        }

    }
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thanks very much. A note to anyone in the future that may be looking at this: close your file in if(*file != NULL). If you try to close it out of that conditional statement, another segmentation fault will be thrown.

Comment: It would be easier and more clear just to return the `FILE *`. You should avoid indirection where possible.

Comment: @Olaf surely. I wanted to do that but then I decided to focus on explaining step by step how to make the OP's code work and let him know what were the mistakes.

Comment: That would be the same for a true function. You answer implies the indirection would be the correct/preferrable way, which it isn't. And you do not even mention to check for error in the caller, too (which also would be easier with a returned `FILE *`)..

Comment: @Olaf I added a notice to stress on the "good way" to do that. However I think that explaining how to pass an "output" parameter to a function is instructive, so I did not want to miss it.